# Cannot reopen error when updating table in SAS with SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I have 2 tables:

- `t1` with columns `A, B, X, Y, Z` and
- `t2` with columns `A, B, N`

I want to set `t1.A` to value `t2.N` where `t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = T2.B`.

It sounds simple, but I have no idea to solve this; I tried something like:

```
update t1 set A = (select t2.N 
                     from t1,t2 
                    where t1.A = t2.A 
                      and t1.B = t2.B)
......
```

But this gives an error:

```
ERROR: You cannot reopen t1.DATA for update access with member-level control because t1.DATA .....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried to clear up the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you just want a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set A = (select t2.N 
             from t2 
             where t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B
            );
```

Note:  You should be careful that the subquery returns only one row.

Answer (score 0):

A side note besides the syntax error: you're getting that `ERROR: You cannot open WORK.T1.DATA for output access with member-level control because WORK.T1.DATA is in use by you in resource environment DATASTEP.` because your output dataset is still open in the window. Close the `VIEWTABLE:Work.T1` prior to re-running.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i closed the window before running so I thought it was a SQL engine Problem, anyway: thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `t1` (we will call it `t1_copy` for example) and use the copy in your select statement. The reason for the table copy is you cannot select from a table you are updating.

```
%_eg_conditional_dropds(t1_copy); /* drop the copy before using it (if one exists) */
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE t1_copy AS
        SELECT * FROM t1;

   update t1 set A = (select t2.N 
                     from t1_copy,t2 
                    where t1_copy.A = t2.A 
                      and t1_copy.B = t2.B)
QUIT;
```